# MonoDevelop do Unity diz que minhas variáveis não existem?

Tags: c#, unity3d, monodevelop

Estava seguindo o quarto vídeo de tutoriais do [*roguelike scavengers*](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLa2bQ5uCFWA15RYHCnhjSbf_LiC4eFEQ0), e me deparei com esses erros ao terminar. No quinto vídeo ele corrige alguns, porém esses continuaram, estou usando a mais recente versão do unity (`5.1f1` sei lá o que mais).

[image: Erros no Unity]

[image: Variáveis não reconhecidas no Mono]

[image: GameObject tileChoice = tileArray(Random.Range(0,tileArray.Length));]

Ele diz que as 3 variáveis em vermelho na imagem não existem naquele contexto, e o outro erro ele aponta para uma linha que aparenta ser normal.

Muito bons os vídeos que tem me animado bastante pra começar o meu projeto!

Eis o código inteiro:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System; //Atributo Serializable - aplica variaveis no inspector e editor
using System.Collections.Generic; //Usar lists
using Random = UnityEngine.Random; //Gerar Numeros Aleatorios

public class BoardManager : MonoBehaviour { //padrao

    [Serializable] //tipo de variavel
    public class Count
    {
        public int minimum;
        public int maximum;

        public Count (int min, int max)
        {
            minimum = min;
            maximum = max;
        }
    }


    public int columns = 8; //Quantidade de colunas do mapa
    public int rows = 8; //Quantidade de Linhas do mapa
    public Count wallCount = new Count (5,9); //quantidade aleatoria de numeros internos
    public Count foodCount = new Count (1,5); //quantidade aleatoria de comida

    public GameObject exit; //objetos do jogo, q vao aparecer no mapa ->
    public GameObject [] floorTiles; 
    public GameObject [] wallTiles;
    public GameObject [] foodTiles;
    public GameObject [] enemyTiles;
    public GameObject [] outerWallTiles; // <- 

    private Transform boardHolder; //segura tds os objetos no mapa
    private List <Vector2> gridPosition = new List<Vector2> (); //lista de posiscoes possiveis no mapa

    void initialiseList () //limpar a lista do grid e preparar para gerar novo mapa
    {
        gridPosition.Clear (); //limpa o mapa
        for (int x=1; x<columns-1; x++) //loop navega pelas colunas
        {
            for (int y=1; y<rows-1; y++)
            {
                gridPosition.Add (new Vector2(x,y));
            }

        }
    }

    void BoardSetup ()
    {
        //starta o mapa e atribui o transform
        boardHolder = new GameObject ("Board").transform;
        for (int x=-1; x<columns+1; x++) 
        {
            for (int y=-1; y<rows+1; y++)
            {
                //seleciona um tile para aplicar no mapa
                GameObject toInstantiate = floorTiles(Random.Range(0,floorTiles.Length));

                //verifica se e muro externo
                if (x == -1 || y == -1 || x == columns || y == rows)
                {
                    toInstantiate = outerWallTiles(Random.Range(0,outerWallTiles.Length));
                }

                GameObject instance = Instantiate (toInstantiate, new Vector2(x,y), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                instance.transform.SetParent (boardHolder);

            }
        }
    }

    //retorna valor para grid position
    Vector2 RandomPosition()
    {
        int randomIndex = Random.Range (0, gridPosition.Count);

        Vector2 randomPosition = gridPosition (randomIndex);

        gridPosition.RemoveAt (randomIndex);

        return randomPosition;
    }

    void LayoutObjectAtRandom(GameObject[] tileArray, int minimum, int maximum)
    {
        int objectCount = Random.Range (minimum, maximum);

        for (int i = 0; i < objectCount; i++) 
        {
            Vector3 randomPosition = RandomPosition();

            GameObject tileChoice = tileArray(Random.Range(0,tileArray.Length));
            Instantiate(tileChoice, randomPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }

    public void SetupScene (int Level)
    {
        BoardSetup (); //starta o mapa

        initialiseList (); //starta o grid

        //instancia numeros aleatorios de muros internos
        LayoutObjectAtRandom (wallTiles, wallCount.minimum, wallCount.maximum);
        //instancia o numero aleatorio de comida
        LayoutObjectAtRandom (foodTiles, foodCount.minimum, foodCount.maximum);

        //seta o numero de enemys baseado no lvl
        int enemyCount = (int)Mathf.Log (Level, 2f);
        LayoutObjectAtRandom (enemyTiles, enemyCount, enemyCount);

        //
        Instantiate (exit, new Vector2 (columns-1, rows-1), Quaternion.identity);
    }

}
```

Comment: Quem é o Nils? Quais videos? Isto parece ser uma pergunta direcionada para uma pessoa em especifico. E o [**Stack Overflow**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com) é uma comunidade! Se você estiver à procura de ajuda de uma certa pessoa, o melhor seria entrar em contacto directamente com ela através de outros meios. Mas se estiver à procura de ajuda da comunidade, então você deve editar e reformular a sua pergunta para que ela seja direcionada para a comunidade e não para uma pessoa só, para que lhe possamos ajudar.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLa2bQ5uCFWA15RYHCnhjSbf_LiC4eFEQ0 esse é o nills !! ele ensina a fazer jogos e recomendeu pra tirar duvidas aqui !! kkkkk mals vc tem razão, fui pensar nisso depois só e deixei a pergunta assim msm, perdão !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu não sou o Nils, mas vou responder sua pergunta. Isso daqui é uma comunidade aonde há milhares de usuários respondendo, e o Nils é apenas um dentre muitos outros. Por causa disso você deveria direcionar a sua pergunta a todos e não apenas a ele.

Mas, de qualquer forma, vamos lá:

---

Isso são arrays:

```
public GameObject [] floorTiles;
public GameObject [] outerWallTiles;
```

Isso é uma lista:

```
private List <Vector2> gridPosition = new List<Vector2> (); //lista de posiscoes possiveis no mapa
```

E isso é um array como parâmetro:

```
void LayoutObjectAtRandom(GameObject[] tileArray, int minimum, int maximum)
```

Isso são tentativas de chamar métodos:

```
GameObject toInstantiate = floorTiles(Random.Range(0,floorTiles.Length));
// ...
toInstantiate = outerWallTiles(Random.Range(0,outerWallTiles.Length));
// ...
Vector2 randomPosition = gridPosition (randomIndex);
// ...
GameObject tileChoice = tileArray(Random.Range(0,tileArray.Length));
```

No entanto `floorTiles`, `outerWallTiles`, `gridPosition` e `tileArray` não são métodos, e sim coleções de objetos.

Acho que o que você queria era isso:

```
GameObject toInstantiate = floorTiles[Random.Range(0, floorTiles.Length)];
// ...
toInstantiate = outerWallTiles[Random.Range(0, outerWallTiles.Length)];
// ...
Vector2 randomPosition = gridPosition[randomIndex];
// ...
GameObject tileChoice = tileArray[Random.Range(0, tileArray.Length)];
```

Ou seja, você usou parênteses `()` ao invés de colchetes `[]`.

- Usar parênteses após o nome de uma variável significa tentar invocar um método com o nome da variável.
- Usar colchetes após uma expressão que resulte em um objeto (e o nome de uma variável é uma expressão) significa tentar acessar uma posição do objeto que deve ser uma lista ou array.

Comment: Muito obrigado cara, eu vou tentar aqui !! kkkkkk sim eu achei q ia ser direcionada direto pra ele !! fui pensar melhor depois só... vou testar aqui !! não conheço nada de c#... acho q alem de seguir as video aulas vou seguir uma apostila a parte tbm pra entender melhor a sintaxe. 

Então, eu resolvi todos os erros que davam com sua ajuda menos o do gridPosition, vc tem ideia do que pode estar causando ele ?

Comment: @PedroF.Neto Algum motivo para ter desfeito a aceitação da resposta depois de tanto tempo? Há algo errado aqui?

Comment: essa semana depois de muito tempo voltei a mexer com esse código e o gridPosition ainda esta dando o mesmo erro, sua solução resolveu algumas coisas mas não todo o problema. Eu vou procurar aprender a sintaxe da linguagem direito

Comment: @PedroF.Neto Se o seu novo problema for parecido com este daqui, acho que você não terá muita dificuldade para achar a solução  aplicando o que tem aqui em seu novo problema. Mas se o seu novo problema for bem diferente, então recomendo que faça uma nova pergunta, pois esta daqui já é bem antiga.